# NSURL problem with unnecessary texts?

Tags: iphone

when i initialize NSString which i get from database,when i print NSLog ,it gives correct URl,but when open through safari, the URL consists %d at the end, how can i remove it?

Comment: while imnk's answer would probably work for this specific problem, it's probably more use to find out where it's coming from! Do you have an example URL string and the code that you use to generate your request object?

Comment: I'm guessing the %d is part of a format string, intended to be replaced by an integer, but the question is pretty vague.

Comment: That's what I figured and NSLog(string) will 'deformat' it so you won't see it in the console :) The %d is likely in the database. I foresee interesting problems when other escape characters get stored in the database and the accepted answer stops catching them ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to remove the %d:

```
NSString *formattedString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"%d" withString:@""];
```

That just replaces **any** %d with nothing... effectively removing it.

---

Or... if you know it always appears at the end of the string you could just slice it:

```
NSString *formattedString = [originalString substringToIndex:[originalString length] - 2];
```

Comment: What if the URL already has some other %d in it that we want to keep intact - your answer would break it. It's probably better to work out where the %d is coming from!